# limit involving a Taylor Polynom

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval, and let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that's at least n-times differentiable.

It needs to be shown that if a polynomial $P(x)$ is of degree $≤ n$, and if for an $a \in I$, it holds true that $lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - P(x)}{(x-a)^n} = 0$, then $P(x)$ is already the Taylor Polynomial $T_n f(x;a)$.

Thanks in advance. I thought that this can be shown by maybe enhancing the limit and adding $T_n f(x;a)$ in-between, and to then show that $T_n f(x;a)$ must be identical to $P(x)$; but I haven't come so far yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct: insert a $T=T_n f(x;a)$ in your fraction as you say. You'll get $\lim \limits_{x \to a} \space \frac {f(x) - T(x)} {(x-a)^n} + \lim \limits_{x \to a} \space \frac {T(x) - P(x)} {(x-a)^n}$.

The first limit is $0$ [*by the definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable) of the Taylor polynomial. This means that the second limit must be $0$ too.

Let $T-P = a_m (x-a)^m + \cdots a_k (x-a)^k$ with $m \leq n$. Assume $T-P \neq 0$. Every nonzero polynomial has a term of *smallest* degree. Let this be $a_k (x-a)^k$ in $T-P$, $a_k \neq 0$. Then the limit of $\frac {T-P} {(x-a)^n}$ is the limit of $\frac {(x-a)^k} {(x-a)^n} (a_m (x-a)^{m-k} + \cdots a_k)$. The part between brackets tends to $a_k$; the fraction preceding it must tend to $\pm \infty$ (which we do not want), unless $k \geq n$. At the same time $k \leq n$, since the degree of $T-P$ is $\leq n$. So $k=n$, and $T-P=a_n(x-a)^n$. Now use that the limit must be $0$ to get $a_n =0$; but we assumed $a_k \neq 0$ - contradiction! Therefore $T-P=0$.

Comment: Thanks; however, I can't quite follow your second part. So we assume that $T ≠ P$ and look at $T - P$ in order to lead that to a contradiction. But why can $T - P$ always be written as $a_m(x - a)^m + ... + a_k(x - a)^k$, when P is just any polynomial? I get that the second limit would be $± \infty$ if $T(a) - P(a) ≠ 0$, but why does it follow then, that k > n? Sorry but Taylor Polynomials are relatively new to me, so it would be appreciated if you could explain a litte more :)

Comment: @moran: I've edited my answer for clarity.